# Priority_queue problems Memory access

Tags: c++, function, memory, priority-queue

I am having some issues with my code.

It seems I cannot access a top of a priority queue only in a specific function.

I get this error :

```
Unhandled exception at at 0x77644B32 in ConsoleApplication5.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::bad_alloc at memory location 0x00D7E6A8.
```

Let me be a little more clear with an example:

if i do a

`cout << *nameofmyqueue->top() ;` in a function called `firstFunction` it'll work perfectly. but if i use it in `otherFunction`, i'll get an access memory error. Here is my code : (there are comments here it works and where it doesn't)

no probs with

```
void Ordinateur::addmessageAEnvoyer(Message* message){
```

doesn t work with

```
void Ordinateur::envoiMessages(){
```

Any ideas why it doesn't work ?

Thanks a lot !

```
#ifndef _ORDINATEUR_H_
#define _ORDINATEUR_H_

#include "PrioriteMessage.h"
#include "Reseau.h"
#include "Message.h"
#include <queue>
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;


class Ordinateur
{
public:
    Ordinateur();
    Ordinateur(string nom,int adresse,Reseau* adresseReseau);
    ~Ordinateur();

    int getAdresse() const; 
    string getNom()const;
    Reseau* getAdresseReseau() const;


    void addmessageAEnvoyer(Message* message);
    void envoiMessages();
    void recoiMessages(Message* messageRecu);
    void afficherMessagesRecus();
    void afficherOrdinateur(ostream& ostr);
    friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& ostr, Ordinateur& ordinateur );

private:
    int adresse_; 
    string nom_;
    Reseau* adresseReseau_;
    priority_queue<Message*,vector<Message*>,PrioriteMessages> listMessagesAEnvoyer_;
    vector<Message*> messagesRecus_;
};

#endif







`#include"Ordinateur.h"

#include <queue>


Ordinateur::Ordinateur(){
    nom_ = "default";
    adresse_ =  0;
}

Ordinateur::Ordinateur(string nom,int adresse,Reseau* adresseReseau){
    nom_ = nom;
    adresse_ =  adresse;
    adresseReseau_ = adresseReseau;
}

Ordinateur::~Ordinateur()
{
}


int Ordinateur::getAdresse()const{
    return adresse_;
}
string Ordinateur::getNom()const{
    return nom_;
}
Reseau* Ordinateur::getAdresseReseau() const{
    return adresseReseau_;
}



void Ordinateur::addmessageAEnvoyer(Message* message){
    listMessagesAEnvoyer_.push (message);
cout << *listMessagesAEnvoyer_.top(); // NO PRPOBLEM HERE
}


void Ordinateur::envoiMessages(){

    cout << *listMessagesAEnvoyer_.top(); // PROBLEM HERE
    while(!listMessagesAEnvoyer_.empty())
    {

        if (listMessagesAEnvoyer_.top()->getnomDestinataire ()!= "0"){
            adresseReseau_->envoiMessageNom(*listMessagesAEnvoyer_.top(),listMessagesAEnvoyer_.top()->getnomDestinataire ());
        }
        else if (listMessagesAEnvoyer_.top()->getnomDestinataire() == "0")
            adresseReseau_->envoiMessageTous(*listMessagesAEnvoyer_.top());

        listMessagesAEnvoyer_.pop();

    }
}

void Ordinateur::recoiMessages(Message* messageRecu){

    cout << nom_ << " #"<< adresse_<<" " <<" Reception d'un message.."<< endl;
    messagesRecus_.push_back (messageRecu);


}

void Ordinateur::afficherOrdinateur (ostream& ostr){
    ostr << nom_ << " #"<< adresse_<<" ";

}

void Ordinateur::afficherMessagesRecus(){
    cout << nom_ << " #"<< adresse_<<" Affichage des messages recus ("<<messagesRecus_.size ()<<"):"<<endl;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < messagesRecus_.size (); i++)
    {
        cout << messagesRecus_[i]<<endl;
    }

}




ostream& operator<<( ostream& ostr, Ordinateur& ordinateur ){

    ordinateur.afficherOrdinateur (ostr);
    return ostr;
}`
```

Comment: Are you sure your queue isn't empty when you call `envoiMessages` ? Although I don't think that should be the issue, considering the exception...

Comment: My crystal ball and rabbits foot tells me you should do the following: Track down the *caller* of `Ordinateur::addmessageAEnvoyer()`. Somewhere near there (shortly after that call) is code that is delet\ing the message you just pushed into your queue. Or, you're pushing the address of a local stack variable and then destroying that var on scope-exit but after its address was pushed into your queue. Either way, you have an invalid pointer in your queue.

Comment: FOUND IT ! i created a local variable called message instead of using Message& so the queue was always emptying itself.....

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer, but more of a suggestion that will hopefully solve your issue.

Given that you didn't post the main(...) or how you are managing the lifetimes of the Messages I would suggest changing the Messages to a std::shared_ptr - that will hopefully make your issue go away.  It would also make determining when you can delete a Message a non-issue.